# JQuery .get in function to return data

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

Trying to return data to var pNow that called .get function.

```
/* set var to server side script */
var pNow = getStime();

function getStime() {
$.get('servertime.asp', function (data) {
  return data;
  //alert(data); 
});
}
```

alert(data) confirms the data is valid and coming from the server side script but not getting returned to the var that called it.

Comment: your $get is a an async call. You need to use a global variable and then assign to that in your success function.

Comment: The link Musa gave has lots of very relevant information. You'll find your answer there.

Answer (score 2):

The callback function in the second argument of `$.get` is an asynchrononous call and will fire after the `getStime` function has already finished its execution. You can use [deferred.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) to get the value as given below.

```
var pNow;
getStime().done(function(data) { pNow = data; });
alert("Use pNow here" + pNow);
function getStime() {
   return $.get('servertime.asp');
}
```

Comment: Adil Thanks for helping but the above code will not work

Comment: Yes, the result doesn't appear to be getting back to pNow

Comment: Do you get data in done ?

Comment: No the function is failing somewhere. I can confirm that the server-side script servertime.asp works correctly

Comment: I have updated me code, did you try it?

Comment: pNow remains 'undefined' in alert

Comment: I've read the deferred.done link and can't account for why this won't work. I understand conceptually that the function needs to wait for the result but it just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
/* set var to server side script */
var pNow = getStime();

function getStime() {
  var newData = null;
  $.get('servertime.asp', function (data) {
     newData = data;
    //alert(data); 
  }).complete(function() {
     return newData;
  });

}
```

Comment: Same problem. That `return` will end the inner call-back function, not the `getStime` function. Remember that you enter a new function scope when you do `function() {...}`